# URL Checker in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a URL checker that I use in Perl.  I was wondering how something like this would be done in Clojure.  I have a file with thousands of URLs and I'd like the output file to contain the URL (minus http://, https://) and a simple :1 for valid and :0 for false.  Ideally, I could check each site concurrently, considering that this is one of Clojure's strengths.

### Input

http://www.google.com
http://www.cnn.com
http://www.msnbc.com
http://www.abadurlisnotgood.com

### Output

www.google.com:1
www.cnn.com:1
www.msnbc.com:1
www.abadurlisnotgood.com:0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume by "valid URL" you mean HTTP response 200.  This might work.  It requires `clojure-contrib`.  Change `map` to `pmap` to attempt to make it parallel, like Arthur Ulfeldt mentioned.

```
(use '(clojure.contrib duck-streams
                       java-utils
                       str-utils))

(import '(java.net URL
                   URLConnection
                   HttpURLConnection
                   UnknownHostException))

(defn check-url [url]
  (str (re-sub #"^(?i)http:/+" "" url)
       ":"
       (try
        (let [c (cast HttpURLConnection
                      (.openConnection (URL. url)))]
          (if (= 200 (.getResponseCode c))
            1
            0))
        (catch UnknownHostException _
          0))))

(defn check-urls-from-file [filename]
  (doseq [line (map check-url
                    (read-lines (as-file filename)))]
    (println line)))
```

Given your example as input:

```
user> (check-urls-from-file "urls.txt")
www.google.com:1
www.cnn.com:1
www.msnbc.com:1
www.abadurlisnotgood.com:0
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a small function that appends a ":1" or ":0" to a url and then use pmap to apply it in parallel to all the urls.

```
(defn check-a-url [url] .... )
(pmap #(if (check-a-url %) (str url ":1") (str url ":0")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Clojure now has a `as-url` function in `clojure.java.io`:

```
(as-url "http://google.com") ;;=> #object[java.net.URL 0x5dedf9bd "http://google.com"]

(str (as-url "http://google.com")) ;;=> "http://google.com"

(as-url "notanurl") ;; java.net.MalformedURLException
```

Based on that we could write a function like so:

```
(defn check-url
  "checks if the url is well formed"
  [url]
  (str (clojure.string/replace-first url #"(http://|https://)" "")
       ":"
       (try (as-url url) ;; built-in, does not perform an actual request, and does very little validation
            1
            (catch Exception e 0))))


(defn check-urls-from-file
  "from Brian Carper answer"
  [filename]
  (doseq [line (map check-url (read-lines (as-file filename)))]
    (println line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pmap, I used agents with send-off in conjunction with the above solution.  I think this is better when there is blocking I/O.  I believe pmap has limited concurrency too.  Here's what I have so far.  I wonder how this will scale with thousands of URLs.

```
(use '(clojure.contrib duck-streams
                       java-utils
                       str-utils))

(import '(java.net URL
                   URLConnection
                   HttpURLConnection
                   UnknownHostException))

(defn check-url [url]
  (str (re-sub #"^(?i)http:/+" "" url)
       ":"
       (try
        (let [c (cast HttpURLConnection
                      (.openConnection (URL. url)))]
          (if (= 200 (.getResponseCode c))
            1
            0))
        (catch UnknownHostException _
          0))))

(def urls (read-lines "urls.txt"))

(def agents (for [url urls] (agent url)))

(doseq [agent agents]
  (send-off agent check-url))

(apply await agents)

(def x '())
(doseq [url (filter deref agents)]
    (def x (cons @url x)))
(prn x)

(shutdown-agents)
```